# Get all Cached Objects which are cached using MemoryCache class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

I want to retrieve all the cache objects that are added using **MemoryCache**.

I tried the below but it is not retrieving them

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();
```

**Note:** Retreive all means not just what i know and created, i mean every cache object that gets created in the application.

Comment: I'm a biti confused by your latest edit. If this answers the question then this really should be added as an answer, not edited into the question. I appreciate that rene told you to edit it into the question but I suspect he didn't realise that it was an answer. Sorry that you are getting mixed messages! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what i found (it may help some one)

```
foreach (var item in MemoryCache.Default)
{
   //add the item.keys to list
}
return list;
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a better way to enumerate and get the result:

```
public virtual List<T> GetCache<T>()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    IDictionaryEnumerator cacheEnumerator = (IDictionaryEnumerator)((IEnumerable)Cache).GetEnumerator();

    while (cacheEnumerator.MoveNext())
        list.Add((T) cacheEnumerator.Value);

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This should also work: `MemoryCache.Default.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private static readonly Type MemoryCacheType = typeof(MemoryCache);
private static readonly FieldInfo CoherentStateFieldInfo = MemoryCacheType.GetField("_coherentState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
private static Type _coherentStateType;

var coherentState = CoherentStateFieldInfo.GetValue(memoryCache);
var coherentStateType = _coherentStateType ??= coherentState?.GetType();
var propertyInfo = coherentStateType!.GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!;

if (propertyInfo.GetValue(coherentState) is not ICollection colecao)
    yield break;
```